# Google Sheet API V4 Returning null ValueRange

Tags: null, google-sheets

I have trying to refer multiple blogs and posts to finally understand what needs to be done to fetch data from Google SpreadSheet using API4 but the valuerange returns null. I am sure I have pass a wrong value somewhere and I would need some help. Please help me out.

My Code of GETDATA.CLASS

```
mService = new com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("Google Sheet Private")
                .build();
```

**Now my first question - Q1**

In the documentation it was given to use the above code to create object of com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets mService.What is Application Name? is it the name of App I am creating(value from AndroidManifest.xml? or the package. Is it anything to do with package name I entered while creating authorization request in google developer console? on logging Log.d("hello","Inside MakeRequest "+mService.toString()); it return me value like this.. 
Inside MakeRequest com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets@945eb81

**Second Question, Q2**

ValueRange return null value

My Code:

```
String spreadsheetId = data.getStringExtra("SSID");
String range = "Class Data!A1:E";
Log.d("hello","mService spreadsheets values                 
                  "+this.mService.spreadsheets().values());
        Log.d("hello","Value Range GET 
                    "+this.mService.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(spreadsheetId, range).getMajorDimension());
```

prints:
**mService spreadsheets values com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets$Spreadsheets$Values@2fb3e61**

**Value Range GET null**

Please help

Comment: Can anybody Please help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed. The google project created in google console should be passed in the below syntax.

```
 mService = new com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets.Builder(
            transport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("GoogleSheet API")
            .build();
```